Update Demographics Object using AMPScript
When trying to update the Contact object using an AMPScript on my SFMC cloud page, my script works fine. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to update the Demographics object using the same script. What would the equivalent of @id = _subscriberkey be for the demographics object. SF support informed me that there should be a demographicsID. The Contact object and demographics object are linked. I don't seem to be able to find a unique identifier for demographics, how can I do this?
%%[

Var @result, @sfObject, @id, @fieldName, @fieldValue
Set @sfObject = "Contact"
Set @id = _subscriberkey
Set @fieldName = "confirmedviaemail__c"
Set @fieldValue = "True"

Set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(@sfObject, @id, @fieldName, @fieldValue)

If @result == 1 then

]%%

Slot Booked for 5 May with %%=v(@id)=%% successfully.

%%[ else ]%%

Slot Booking for 5 May with ID %%=v(@id)=%% was not updated.

%%[ EndIf ]%%

I am sorry if my question doesn't make sense, I am trying to learn.

What are you updating in the Demographics object?  If it's something related to the Contact, you'll need to retrieve the necessary Id from Contact in order to update it in the Demographics object.  You'll likely need to use the RetrieveSalesforceObjects function to do that.

I am trying to update the same field "confirmedviaemail__c". After having it updated for contact, my company decided, they wanted all the information to be stored under the Demographics object

And ContactID is the field in common between Contact and Demographics?

Yes, contact ID is the common field

If the relationship between Contact and Demographics is Contact ID, then you can just update both:
%%[

set @contactID = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")

set @result = 0
set @result2 = 0

if not empty(@contactID) then 
  set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Contact", @contactID, "confirmedviaemail__c", "True")
  set @result2 = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Demographics", @contactID, "confirmedviaemail__c", "True")
endif

If @result == 1 and @result2 == 1 then

]%%

Slot Booked for 5 May with ID %%=v(@contactID)=%% successfully.

%%[ else ]%%

Slot Booking for 5 May with ID %%=v(@contactID)=%% was not updated.

%%[ EndIf ]%%


Thanks, I'll try this out!
